How to update and extend dataframe1 with values from dataframe2
I have a dataframe df_old that I want to update with new values from df_new. The dataframes have exactly the same structure, each has records with a first column 'DateTime' that serves as the key column. The result should be a dataframe that is basically a concatenation of df_old and df_new but for every duplicate key only the new record (from df_new) is kept. How can i accomplish this?
df_old:
DateTime     B     C

2024-09-21   12.9  5.4
2024-09-22   13.1  5.4

df_new:
DateTime     B     C

2024-09-22   13.2  5.2
2024-09-23   13.4  4.9

df_updated:
DateTime     B     C

2024-09-21   12.9  5.4
2024-09-22   13.2  5.2 <-- new values overwrite the old ones
2024-09-23   13.4  4.9



concat two dfs
drop duplicates
keep last will ensure we keep data from df_new since df_new is put after df_old in concat

import pandas as pd


df_old = pd.DataFrame({
    'DateTime': ['2024-09-21', '2024-09-22'],
    'B': [12.9, 13.1],
    'C': [5.4, 5.4]
})
df_new = pd.DataFrame({
    'DateTime': ['2024-09-22', '2024-09-23'],
    'B': [13.2, 13.4],
    'C': [5.2, 4.9]
})
result = pd.concat([df_old, df_new]).drop_duplicates(subset='DateTime', keep='last')

# explain
intermediate = pd.concat([df_old, df_new])
print(intermediate)
#      DateTime     B    C
# 0  2024-09-21  12.9  5.4
# 1  2024-09-22  13.1  5.4
# 0  2024-09-22  13.2  5.2
# 1  2024-09-23  13.4  4.9

res = intermediate.drop_duplicates(subset='DateTime', keep='last')
print(res)
#      DateTime     B    C
# 0  2024-09-21  12.9  5.4
# 0  2024-09-22  13.2  5.2
# 1  2024-09-23  13.4  4.9


Here's one approach:

Use Series.isin to find matches for df_old['DateTime'] inside df_new['DateTime'].
Use the inverse of the result (~) for boolean indexing, before passing df_old to pd.concat.

out = pd.concat([
    df_old[~df_old['DateTime'].isin(df_new['DateTime'])],
    df_new
    ], ignore_index=True)

Output:
     DateTime     B    C
0  2024-09-21  12.9  5.4
1  2024-09-22  13.2  5.2
2  2024-09-23  13.4  4.9


An alternative to consider, is to make DateTime the index (df.set_index), in which case this becomes really easy with df.combine_first:
df_old = pd.DataFrame({
    'DateTime': ['2024-09-21', '2024-09-22'],
    'B': [12.9, 13.1],
    'C': [5.4, 5.4]
}).set_index('DateTime')

df_new = pd.DataFrame({
    'DateTime': ['2024-09-22', '2024-09-23'],
    'B': [13.2, 13.4],
    'C': [5.2, 4.9]
}).set_index('DateTime')

out = df_new.combine_first(df_old)

Output:
               B    C
DateTime             
2024-09-21  12.9  5.4
2024-09-22  13.2  5.2
2024-09-23  13.4  4.9

